# Given two lists of strings, find the total number of strings in the second list which contains any string in the first list as substring

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
ListA = ['are','stop','kill']
ListB = ['never','fullstop','nonstop','area','AreYou','stoppable','point']
```

we have two strings in `ListB` with substring 'are' and three with 'stop'. none with 'kill'. so the answer is 5. Edit: Case insensitive matches

Can we do this using list comprehension ?

Comment: If `ListB` had a string `'stopkill'` would you count it once or twice?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski only once..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a simple way, but I get 4:

```
>>> sum(a in b for a in ListA for b in ListB)
4
```

Unless you want to be case-insensitive

```
>>> sum(a.lower() in b.lower() for a in ListA for b in ListB)
5
```

As stated, though, your question is ambiguous: this method counts how many *matches* there are. If you want to count how many *words* in `ListB` have a match, you could do this:

```
>>> len(set(b for a in ListA for b in ListB if a.lower() in b.lower()))
5
```

As an example of where it differs:

```
>>> ListA = ['stop', 'kill']
>>> ListB = ['stoppable', 'killable', 'stopkill']

>>> sum(a.lower() in b.lower() for a in ListA for b in ListB)
4
>>> len(set(b for a in ListA for b in ListB if a.lower() in b.lower()))
3
```

Comment: I guess i meant how many matches. Didn't quite knew how to frame it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
>>> ListA = ['are','stop','kill']
>>> ListB = ['never','fullstop','nonstop','area','AreYou','stoppable','point']
>>> len([b for b in ListB if any(filter(lambda a: a in b.lower(), ListA))])
5
```